# "please run connect() first" - On second try

Tags: python

I have a python script that I've been using for the last couple of months without any issues.
On my last attempt of running the script I encountered the "please run connect() first" error.

I've reviewed related questions here, but in my case the behaviour is kinda odd.
The e-mail sending function ran twice (as expected) - but I got the error only for the second function call (running in a loop).

Not sure why it would work for the first function call, but not for the second one.
I'll also say that it's not the first time I'm calling the function twice, but it's the first time it failed on the second call.

Hopfully that someone has an idea what could cause the error, and how to fix it.
Thanks in advance for the help.

```
smtp_host = 'AWS' // Not the real value
port = 465
message = "my message"
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_host, port, 'email.com')
msg = EmailMessage()
msg.set_content(message)

msg['Subject'] = "maintenance"
msg['From'] = 'test1@email.com'
msg['To'] = 'test2@email.com'

server.login(args.email_name, args.email_passwd)
server.send_message(msg)   
server.quit()
```

Edit:

The same issue happened again, this time I was able to pull out the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jenkins/workspace/NOC_Maintenance_Scheduler_master/NOC_Scripts/Maintenance_Scheduler/SQL_Email.py", line 43, in execute_send
    server.login(args.email_name, args.email_passwd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 693, in login
    self.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 599, in ehlo_or_helo_if_needed
    if not (200 <= self.ehlo()[0] <= 299):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 439, in ehlo
    self.putcmd(self.ehlo_msg, name or self.local_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 366, in putcmd
    self.send(str)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 358, in send
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected('please run connect() first')
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first
```

Comment: "the "please run connect() first" error." - this description is not helpful. Please show the entire error message - including the traceback, copied and pasted, formatted as code.

Comment: Apologies, but unfortunately I don't have the entire error message as it was not captured by the machine that ran it. If what I have provided is not enough - I guess i'll just have to wait for it to happen again.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I have edited my post with the traceback